# Object as key in map mongoose is not storing

Tags: mongodb, dictionary, mongoose

I want to store map to db but it's not working when I add object as a key

```
const ChatSchema = new Schema({
    chat: Map
})

const Chat = mongoose.model("Chat", ChatSchema)

const chats = new Map([[
    {name: "Nina"}, [{ name: "Umar", msg: "Hey Sup" }, { name: "Umar", msg: "I'm good, wbu?" }],
]])

console.log(c)
```

Output: `{ _id: 6115c9d47f76262114e35c1e }`

*Any ideas?*